# Custom positioning of elements (relative to other object)

Tags: positioning

Is there a way to position text objects relative to other objects?

My current code:

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
    10
    6.666666666666667
    5.9259259259259265
    5.83088884457784
\end{verbatim}
\ \ \ \ \ \ $\vdots$
\begin{verbatim}
    5.818578011589186
    5.818578011589186
    5.818578011589186
\end{verbatim}
\ \ \ \ \ \ $\vdots$
\end{framed}
```

I am placing blank spaces in front of the `\vdots`because I want them to be centered relative to the numbers:

[image: output screenshot]

Is there an elegant way to do this (i.e. without having to guess the amount of spaces needed, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc` package to estimate the width of the longest line and pass that width to `\makebox` to center the `\vdots` within that width, see below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{framed,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
10
6.666666666666667
5.9259259259259265
5.83088884457784
\end{verbatim}
\makebox[\widthof{5.9259259259259265}]{$\vdots$}
\begin{verbatim}
5.818578011589186
5.818578011589186
5.818578011589186
\end{verbatim}
\makebox[\widthof{5.9259259259259265}]{$\vdots$}
\end{framed}
\makebox[\widthof{5.9259259259259265}]{$\vdots$}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works, thanks! That screenshot is not the `\makebox` version though, is it?

Comment: I've updated it according to the code. By default, `verbatim` takes all spaces literally, so, if you indent a line it will appear indented in the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to center something in a column and you are searching an elegant way, you can use `\halign`:

```
\halign{\tt#\unskip\hfil\cr
    10                  \cr
    6.666666666666667   \cr
    5.9259259259259265  \cr
    5.83088884457784    \cr
    \hfil $\vdots$      \cr
    5.818578011589186   \cr
    5.818578011589186   \cr
    5.818578011589186   \cr
    \hfil $\vdots$      \cr
}

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks, this addresses the problem directly. Can I then put the numbers in a `verbatim` environment?

Comment: Why in verbatim envionment?

Comment: It's a Python program's output, and want to show it with this font format (code-like)

Comment: This font format is realized by `\tt`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `verbatim` is for; anyway, with `fancyvrb` you have `BVerbatim` that makes a box which `tabular` can measure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\noindent\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\begin{BVerbatim}[codes={\baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip}]
10
6.666666666666667
5.9259259259259265
5.83088884457784
\end{BVerbatim}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$\vdots$} \\[6pt]
\begin{BVerbatim}[codes={\baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip}]
5.818578011589186
5.818578011589186
5.818578011589186
\end{BVerbatim}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$\vdots$}
\end{tabular}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\ttfamily\noindent\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
10 \\
6.666666666666667 \\
5.9259259259259265 \\
5.83088884457784 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$\vdots$} \\[6pt]
5.818578011589186 \\
5.818578011589186 \\
5.818578011589186 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$\vdots$}
\end{tabular}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```